# JBoss CLI list MDBs

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-cli

I am trying to implement some simple monitoring using the DMR API, so far I can list all the datasources and then get for each one some statistics with the following cli expression ***[/subsystem=datasources:read-resource(recursive=true)]*** translated to Java:

```
ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
ModelNode op = request.get(ClientConstants.OP);
op.set(ClientConstants.READ_RESOURCE_OPERATION);
request.get(ClientConstants.RECURSIVE).set(true);
ModelNode address = request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR);
address.add(ClientConstants.SUBSYSTEM, "datasources");
final ModelNode response = verify(client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build()));
List<ModelNode> list = response.get(ClientConstants.RESULT).get("data-source").asList();
for (ModelNode node : list) {
    String dsName = node.keys().iterator().next();
    //...Check for each ds using the cli expression
    //[/subsystem=datasources/data-source=dsName/statistics=pool:read-resource(recursive=true, include-runtime=true)]
}
```

But if I try to do the same for ejb3 using the cli expression ***[/subsystem=ejb3:read-resource(recursive=true)]*** I don't get a list of ejb3 but something different.

I know I can get what I am looking for if I already know the name of the app and its mdb with the cli expression ***[/deployment=App.war/subsystem=ejb3/message-driven-bean=Consumer:read-resource(include-runtime=true)]*** but I have many so I don't want to include a list of them.

Any expert out there that could help me?

Thanks!

Johann

Answer (score 0):

Before you start collecting ejb statistics, you need to add "statistics" attribute and enable it in the ejb3 subsystem.
Please find below the coresponding CLI command:

```
#Standalone Mode
/subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name=enable-statistics, value=true)
```